# Cron job settings

Tags: cron, schedule

I'm working on ubuntu. I've configured cron job in config.xml

```
 <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <my_cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>helloworld/observer::doSomething</model>
                </run>
            </my_cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

and observer function is as follow

```
public function doSomething()
    {
        Mage::log("Ya", null, 'obs.log');

    }
```

After doing these settings, I don't see cron scheduled in `cron_schedule` table. When I run localhost/magento/cron.php file, cron is registered in `cron_schedule` table.

*How I can configure it such that I don't have to run cron.php every time and cron schedule will be registered in `cron_schedule` table?*

Also, I want to run it every 1 minute by using `<cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>` but in `cron_schedule` table it says, it's scheduled at 2015-07-15 04:57:00, which is not just a minute away.

Comment: Hi Amit, Have you configured crontab in your ubuntu?? Like by running crontab -e and 1 * * * * php -f magento-directory/cron.php

Comment: @GirishSH: not yet. If I run crontab -e, it says "no crontab for amit - using an empty one".

Comment: Also I tried putting path in crontab 1* * * * /var/www/html/magento/cron.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your cron job to run every minute then put this in the crontab:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/magento/cron.sh
```

Also this is a nice reading I think could help you to set cron groups:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/56375/5913

Comment: I tried * * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/magento/cron.sh and */1 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/magento/cron.sh, still I don't see any entry in cron_schedule table.